# What is the difference between "a problem with his leg" & "a problem of his leg"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

Ok, [in Longman dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/with),

> “With” used to say what an action or situation is related to
>
> We have a problem with parking in this area.
>
> Be careful with that glass.
>
> Is there something wrong with your phone?
>
> How are you getting on with your studies, David?
>
> Compared with other children of the same age, Robert is very tall.

See this sentence:

**He walks with a stick because of a problem with his leg**

So, "**a problem with his leg**" means "**a problem related to / connected with his leg**"

In oxford dictionary,

> "of" belonging to something; being part of something; relating to
>   something
>
> the lid of the box
>
> the director of the company
>
> a member of the team
>
> the result of the debate

See this sentence:

**He walks with a stick because of a problem of his leg**

So, "**a problem of his leg**" means "**a problem belonging to his leg**"

So, What is the difference between "**a problem with his leg**" & "**a problem of his leg**"?

or **are they the same?**

Answer (score 5):

It is not idiomatic English to say "a problem of his leg".

Prepositions, in general, cannot really be understood on their own. Different phrases use different prepositions, and not always in entirely predictable ways. We say, "a question of usage," "a matter of usage," but "a problem with usage." We would say "a disease of the immune system," but "a problem with the immune system." Why? It's not really clear. Part of learning any language is learning which preposition is typically used in which situation.

If you say, "a problem of his leg," most speakers would guess what you mean, but many would correct you, and say you should replace "of" with "with" in that setting.